# In-place modification of object of discriminated union

Tags: typescript, discriminated-union

I have a variable whose type is a discriminated union, and I want to change it (in place) to another part of the discriminated union.

See the example below, if the argument is in the `{isNumber: false, valueStr: string}` type I want to change it to `{isNumber: true, valueNum: number}`, and conversely.
But obviously it doesn’t work, because in the branches of the if statement the type of `arg` is narrowed, and there is now no way to change it.

I tried all sorts of tricks, various type assertions, simultaneous assignment, and so on, but still couldn’t find a way to make Typescript happy.

Is there any way (ideally typesafe) to write this function?

```js
type T = {isNumber: true, valueNum: number} | {isNumber: false, valueStr: string};

const toggle = (arg: T): void => {
    if (arg.isNumber) {
        arg.isNumber = false;
        arg.valueStr = `${arg.valueNum}`;
        delete arg.valueNum;
    } else {
        arg.isNumber = true;
        arg.valueNum = parseInt(arg.valueStr);
        delete arg.valueStr;
    }
}
// ^ Lots of red, how to make it work? (ideally typesafe)
```

Comment: This will not work... The best you can do is to reassign arg to a different variable with the type `{isNumber: boolean, valueNum?: number, valueStr?: string}`. This way the compiler will not be angry about the properties not being on the object.

Comment: @Akxe, right but then I lose type safety and could turn it into an invalid value :(

Comment: Normally you should use discriminated unions like "value types", where the identity of an object is not important, and so you should not have a reason to modify the object in-place rather than create a new object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do is fundamentally not a type-safe operation and the compiler won't allow you to do it without using [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions).

After narrowing, there's no going back to a supertype without reassigning. Consider this example which only uses primitives:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/DYUwLgBAbghsCuIIF4IHICMaIwM4VzACcBLAOwHMIAfCM+AWwCMQiBuAKA5IDMIAKMAE8ADiAD2fWAiTI56QqUpoAlBADeHCNDiIOAen0A9APxadMlBABMnQ6fPS99swF8gA)

```ts
let value = '1' as string | number;

if (typeof value === 'string') {
  value
//^? let value: string
  value = 2;
//^? let value: string | number
  value
//^? let value: number
}
```

---

Now, on the data in your question: Below are two methods for conversion that both effort to at least be explicit about the types involved at each step of the mutations.

Here are type aliases for the types in the union:

```ts
type BoxedNum = { isNumber: true, valueNum: number };
type BoxedStr = { isNumber: false, valueStr: string };
type Box = BoxedNum | BoxedStr;
```

First approach:

1. The alternate box data structure is created.
2. Then, using an [inline type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions), the exclusive property is `delete`d from the box. In order for a property to be eligible for deletion in TypeScript, it must be [optional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties).
3. Finally, [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) is used to assign the properties of the alternate box to the argument box.

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#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)

```ts
function toggle (box: Box): void {
  if (box.isNumber) {
    const boxedStr: BoxedStr = {
      isNumber: false,
      valueStr: box.valueNum.toString(),
    };
    delete (box as Partial<BoxedNum>).valueNum;
    Object.assign(box, boxedStr); // overwrites property values
  }
  else {
    const boxedNum: BoxedNum = {
      isNumber: true,
      valueNum: parseInt(box.valueStr),
    };
    delete (box as Partial<BoxedStr>).valueStr;
    Object.assign(box, boxedNum); // overwrites property values
  }
}
```

Second approach:

1. Create the alternate box value.
2. Delete the exclusive property.
3. Create a reference to the argument box, but use a type assertion to cast it to the alternate type.
4. Directly assign the property values.

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAQg9gDwgEwHIFcC2UC8UDeUAlgM4aYBGEATgFxTDXoQDcUAbgIYA2z59AOyxVqUAL4sAUKEixEKAMqNcBYmWE16AMx4lWHHsyV0oJRkQEBzcVJnR4CFQ5TkoAHzlJkxqZK3oBAGNgIjgBBjhLS25oAAoKRHoHAEp6djgiZAJJKGItKHjEADpSchFk7NzcwLCzU2U8BIQirl4IciLgOGMLS1jkqSqoZAgY4DimqE4SKAAFTmoQngAeZzQsAD5klsN2rEGqmoE66gh8xsQpmYCAawE4AHdw6c9FRgPc060S9UoaFR03D0HygXx2bWMKjM1AOYhyUFGekqh1qwCgQmweDACz0AEkBMBCs1WkZGAN4bkRmMJpcXvNFkQVmtjFtwaSYRSoEcTmcVJMXrd7k8rq91pgQWDShpRHhGMwJWc2XtMej9vC4XDJNy0U0AIxJS54fDwqV-ExyiAAGnhJOV9F11okki1qKgTQATAbHEaTb8RNpdFabbtjPQAOTusOO3zcuAxIrcSKxfB6y1uxDusTk6SRaIQIm68ldKIxInu8mx+OJvopxAO9MITPZ4t5gtF3Olj0V2pxiAJpO1hD1j1ZqRAA)

```ts
function toggle (box: Box): void {
  if (box.isNumber) {
    const str = box.valueNum.toString();
    delete (box as Partial<BoxedNum>).valueNum;
    const ref = box as unknown as BoxedStr;
    ref.isNumber = false;
    ref.valueStr = str;
  }
  else {
    const num = parseInt(box.valueStr);
    delete (box as Partial<BoxedStr>).valueStr;
    const ref = box as unknown as BoxedNum;
    ref.isNumber = true;
    ref.valueNum = num;
  }
}
```

---

Rather than either of these, I suggest using a [pure function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function) to create the alternate box type (using an [overloaded function signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) for even better DX):

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAQg9gDwgEwHIFcC2UC8UDeUAlgM4aYBGEATgFxTDXoQDcUAbgIYA2z59AOyxVqUAL4sAUKEixEKAMqNcBYmWE16AMx4lWHHsyV0oJRkQEBzcVJnR4CFQ5TkoAHzlJkxqZK3oBAGNgIjgBKEDqCE5gCABBbljqARjoAAoKRHpnNCwASmz5b0YpfyCQsIio1ISklNioDKzPRUYCltzMUoDg0PDI6Njamnr0zIRChHaHbvK+qsH4xJHUxvHJvIJJKGItNcQAOlJyEU38bZ2IsLMocdaTHOMVc8vL440THW49ABoL164vAgxno4wOgL4WAOwDgxgsljSeT+rwk-ygUWA6GStyKPguYkkF0C12AOK8-A6rjwLze6komgYTAgyMuEIgFLAnGoegAkgJgE0EODDMC2izUTsMVjwndOpICZJiQIbuMAIyTZ4Xd70kyMZgstkU1V-VGKklkgBMGupWrpIm0umZFzZIKgAHILW6Tb4lSQ4NwIAduHAETS1SzxhaTXkfebxgBmFQDGrLZKpQWqmNm5Wk8YAFiT1SGqdGgotWezfoDQZDaTDiGNF0jEcQ8ZbCDz0ZYQA)

```ts
function createAlternate (box: BoxedNum): BoxedStr;
function createAlternate (box: BoxedStr): BoxedNum;
function createAlternate (box: Box): Box;
function createAlternate (box: Box) {
  if (box.isNumber) {
    const boxedStr: BoxedStr = {
      isNumber: false,
      valueStr: box.valueNum.toString(),
    };
    return boxedStr;
  }

  const boxedNum: BoxedNum = {
    isNumber: true,
    valueNum: parseInt(box.valueStr),
  };
  return boxedNum
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, you should not mutate your values, because TypeScript [does not like it](https://catchts.com/mutations), however, this is only my opinion (experience). Personally I consider it as a bad practice (only if you do frontend). Apart from that, if you have an object with two properties, I think you can easily avoid any mutations and create completely new object with appropriate properties.

Consider this eaxmple:

```js
interface NumberValue {
  isNumber: true,
  valueNum: number
}

interface StringValue {
  isNumber: false,
  valueStr: `${number}`
}

type Item = NumberValue | StringValue

/**
 * Extract number from string digit
possible since T.S. 4.8 https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/48094
 */
type ParseInt<T extends `${number}`> =
  T extends any
  ? (T extends `${infer Digit extends number}`
    ? Digit
    : never)
  : never

interface MakeString<T extends NumberValue['valueNum']> {
  isNumber: false,
  valueStr: `${T}`
}

interface MakeDigit<T extends StringValue['valueStr']> {
  isNumber: true,
  valueNum: ParseInt<T>
}

const stringValue = <StringNumber extends `${number}`>(value: StringNumber) =>
  ({ isNumber: true, valueNum: parseInt(value) })

const numberValue = <Digit extends number>(value: Digit) =>
  ({ isNumber: false, valueStr: `${value}` })

function toggle<Num extends number, T extends NumberValue & { valueNum: Num }>(arg: T): MakeString<T['valueNum']>
function toggle<Str extends `${number}`, T extends StringValue & { valueStr: Str }>(arg: T): MakeDigit<T['valueStr']>
function toggle<T extends Item>(arg: T): Item
function toggle<T extends Item>(arg: T) {
  return arg.isNumber ? numberValue(arg.valueNum) : stringValue(arg.valueStr)
}

// {
//     isNumber: false;
//     valueStr: "42";
// }
const _ = toggle({
  isNumber: true,
  valueNum: 42
})

// {
//     isNumber: true;
//     valueNum: 42; // as digit
// }
const __ = toggle({
  isNumber: false,
  valueStr: '42.01'
})

// expected error because state is illegal
const ___ = toggle({
  isNumber: true,
  valueStr: '42'
})

const payload = {
  isNumber: true,
  valueNum: 42
}

/**
 * Error, because [isNumber] is infered as boolean,
 * whereas it should be [true]
 */
const ____ = toggle(payload)
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/W4xBXW)

As you might have noticed I have created utilities for different data structures. Also, you are getting literal type inference out of the box. However, there are still some `unsafe` places which you should be aware of.

```js
const ____ = toggle({
  isNumber: true,
  valueNum: NaN
})
const test = ____.valueStr //`${number}`, but runtime value is "NaN"

const _____ = toggle(____)
const test2 = _____.valueNum // number, but runtime is null

console.log({ _____ })
```

In order to make it safer, we should forbid using wider `number` type an allow using only literal safe numbers.
If you are type fanatic, you can add more custom typeguards to check whether it is safe number and not NaN, etc ...
Let me know if you have any questions